# How to do Elixir mixins

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to create a mixins for authentication login, so it can be applied to my models which should be able to login. Much like the the has_secure_password in Ruby.

Afaik this is done using the `use` statement which essential requires the module, and calls the `__using__` macro. So I implemented my mixin like this.

```
defmodule MyApp.SecurePassword do
  defmacro __using__(_options) do
    quote do
      import MyApp.SecurePassword
    end
  end

  defmacro authenticate(password) do
    # Lets return true, for testing purposes.
    true
  end
end
```

I'm then calling the use, in my "user" model.

```
defmodule MyApp.Farm do
  use MyApp.Web, :model
  use MyApp.SecurePassword

  schema "farms" do
    field :name, :string
    field :email, :string
  #.....
```

In my controller, i'm then trying to use the method.

```
 def create(conn, %{"session" => session_params}) do
    user = Repo.get_by(Farm, email: session_params["email"])

    if user && user.authenticate(session_params["password"]) do
      conn = put_flash(conn, :success, "You were successfully logged in")
    else
      conn = put_flash(conn, :error, "Credentials didn't match")
    end

    redirect(conn, to: session_path(conn, :new))
 end
```

But when i hit the code, i just get a argument error, on the line where i call the authenticate function.

My macro skills is rather weak, what am i doing wrong? :)

Comment: It is worth to point out that Elixir does not have objects so we don't really have "mixins". `user.authenticate(...)` is not valid in Elixir, you *cannot* call functions on your structs. They are just data by design.

Comment: Aah yes of course, too much language switching :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you want is to call the `authenticate` function passing in the user and the password:

```
def authenticate(user, password) do
  # auth logic
end
```

And then:

```
import MyApp.SecurePassword
# ...
if user && authenticate(user, session_params["password"]) do
# ...
```

For now there doesn't seem to be any reason to use a macro or a `use`, a simple `import` will do - you only want those when generating some code compile-time and in this case it seems everything you want will be happening at runtime.

Comment: Yes, perfect answer. Thinking about mixins in Elixir is conceptually wrong in the majority of cases. Relying on composition is a cleaner and a much better approach.